# Can Async HttpClient post request to https?

Tags: java, asynchronous, post, https

I am using `asyncHttpClient` to make post request and it is working fine.

But for one of the license server, post request is always coming in failure call back. And it is giving error message `"bad Request"` and `status 400`.

This post request is sent to `https` url not like other request I am making to `http`.

Can asyncHttpCLient make post to https? If yes, then what is the difference between http post and https post in terms of asyncHtppClient post request.

I am very new to java, so may be missing some basic step.

I am using com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you are passing request body as expected by the API?

Comment: Yes, as per api documentation it does not need anything in body

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes.  From the libraries [website](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) it says that it is built on the [apache http components](https://hc.apache.org/) which support secure (https) connections.

The sample code right on the front page even shows it using a secure URL.

import com.loopj.android.http.*;

```
public class TwitterRestClient {
  private static final String BASE_URL = "https://api.twitter.com/1/";

  private static AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

  public static void get(String url, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler) {
      client.get(getAbsoluteUrl(url), params, responseHandler);
  }

  public static void post(String url, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler) {
      client.post(getAbsoluteUrl(url), params, responseHandler);
  }

  private static String getAbsoluteUrl(String relativeUrl) {
      return BASE_URL + relativeUrl;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but only `get` example is given in [link](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/). Do you have any example that shows `post` request

Comment: One might suggest that you carefully read the second function in the sample code...

Comment: @lscoughlin, For us newbies to asyncHttpClient, the second function lack clarity in how to do some pretty popular things needed for RESTful stuff, like setting the header, and reading the result. Any idea how to do those things? Also, is it ok for `params` to be a json string? Any additional detail is helpful.